# How to create RtfWriter2 document using iText PDF OutputStream?

Tags: pdf-generation, itext, rtf

I am using the free version of iText (v2.1.7 in particular. Can't use AGPL version due to tight project budget) to create PDF and RTF docs. 
I have an external interface (with no access to its source code) which creates a PDF and returns a `OutputStream` object. My requirement is to create a `RtfWriter2` document using this `OutputStream` object. Below is the signature of that external interface method.

```
public OutputStream getPDFOutputStream();
```

Let me know if what I am trying to achieve is technically possible using iText 2.1.7.

Comment: As a sidenote, the latest versions of iText are free too, just under a different license (AGPL instead of GPL). Please also note that you are using a version of iText that is more than 5 years old. Since then, a lot of bugs have been fixed, and intellectual property issues have been resolved. As a consequence, using this old version exposes your customers as well as yourself to technical and possibly legal risks.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but I am aware of the information already. It is for avoiding AGPL license that we are using iText v2.1.7.

Comment: You can also avoid the AGPL by purchasing a license (which admittedly could be a no-go, depending on your budget and how much of it you can/want to dedicate to good and up-to-date tools).

Comment: It seems like you are insisting on mentioning the obvious things

Comment: RTF has been abandoned after iText 2.1.7. It is a dead project without any support whatsoever. Please look for another product. (I can say this because I'm the one who originally wrote iText.)